# Filtro de productos solo se muestra en el primer modal

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

tengo un filtro de productos en cada modal. Los modales tienen una id distinta. dependiendo del ID muestra información.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que mi filtro de productos solo funciona en el primer modal.
**Como puedo solucionar esto?**

HTML:

```
<select class="form-select w-50 m-auto mb-5 text-center" id="select">
      <option class="select" value="todos">Todos</option>
      <option class="select" value="bebidas">Bebidas</option>
      <option class="select" value="abarrotes">Abarrotes</option>
      <option class="select" value="electro">Electro</option>
    </select>
    <div class="contenedor d-flex flex-wrap p-2" id="contenedor">

    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>

const ListProducts = [

 
    @foreach($nombres as $productos)
    {
        name: '{{$productos->nombre}}',
        img: '{{$productos->imagen}}',
        categoria: '{{$productos->categoria}}'
    },
 @endforeach

]

const contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor')
//const nav = document.getElementById('nav')
const select = document.getElementById('select')

const AddAll_Products = (list) => {
    contenedor.innerHTML = ''
    list.map(item => (
        contenedor.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card card-body mx-2 mb-3 text-center">
        <img class="m-auto" src=${item.img} />
        <p class="font-weigth btn btn-primary">${item.name}</p>
    </div>
    `
    ))
}

AddAll_Products(ListProducts);

const FilterProducts = (categoria) => {
    let product = ListProducts.filter(item => item.categoria === categoria)
    contenedor.innerHTML = '';
    AddAll_Products(product)
}



select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value
    value === 'todos' ? AddAll_Products(ListProducts) : FilterProducts(e.target.value)
})


</script>
```

**El problema es que la busqueda que haga el filtro la refleja solamente en el primer modal y necesito que funcione en todos los Modales**

ayuda por favor

Comment: porque tener un modal por cada habitacion si puedes tener un solo modal, cuando den click sobre la habitacion agregar productos a esa habitacion. Si vas a tener un modal por cada habitacion vas a tener demasiado codigo redundante e inutil.

Comment: @David081 Tienes razón, pero como hago para tener un solo modal y al abrirlo mostrar el contenido dinámico??

Comment: Pues no se de donde sacas la informacion pero supongo que es de una base de datos. Debes crear un modal y cuando hagas la peticion a la base de datos, obtener ese modal por su id, vaciar el contenido de el y llenarlo con la informacion nueva. 
Para poder obtener una mejor ayuda debes [edit] ya agregar mas antecedentes a tu pregunta o formular una nueva pregunta.